# I'm unable to add column widget inside flexible widget, error: A value of type Null cant be assigned to parameter of type Widget in const constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to put column() widget inside Flexible and/or Expanded widget, but i am getting following error, i don't know why this is occurring, can anybody please let me know how can i put column() widget inside Flexible Widget.

I am getting following erros:

```
Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.dart(const_eval_throws_exception)
A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'Widget' in a const constructor.
Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'.dartconst_constructor_param_type_mismatch
The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.dartconst_with_non_const
The values in a const list literal must be constants.
Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.dartnon_constant_list_element
The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.dartconst_with_non_const
The values in a const list literal must be constants.
Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.dartnon_constant_list_element
```

Flutter Version

> Flutter 2.5.0 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework •  revision
> 4cc385b4b8 (5 weeks ago) •  2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700 Engine •
> revision f0826da7ef Tools •  Dart 2.14.0

below is complete Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var outline_borders;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(65, 135, 217, 1),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            SizedBox(height: 180),
            Text(
              "Get Started",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                  fontSize: 25),
            ),
            
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Enter your phone number :"),
                  
                ],
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: AppThemeData.lightTheme,
      home: SignIn(),
    );
  }
}
```

below is the screenshot of errors that i am getting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `const` from UI where you declared in front of the widget. That's also mentioned in your editor dialog.

Remove const from `Column` children

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var outline_borders;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(65, 135, 217, 1),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children:  [ // here you need to update and const removed
            SizedBox(height: 180),
            Text(
              "Get Started",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                  fontSize: 25),
            ),

            Flexible(
                flex: 2,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("Enter your phone number :"),

                  ],
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: AppThemeData.lightTheme,
      home: SignIn(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: there isn't any const keyword in that particular UI. Where exactly are you want me to remove const keyword?

Comment: can you share more code?

Comment: i updated, you can see the complete code now.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is due to using the keyword **const**   widget. Just remove it and you will be all good.